# Flatten a subarray in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Input:

```
postgres=> select sets from matches limit 2;

         sets         
----------------------
 {{6,4},{6,2}}
 {{6,3},{5,7},{10,4}}

(2 rows)
```

Expected (Sum of the value in each array)

```
postgres=> select sets from matches limit 2;

         sets         
----------------------
 18
 33

(2 rows)
```

I tried, but it only gives me the value of two first value in the first sub array:

```
postgres=> select unnest(sets) from matches limit 2;

 unnest 
--------
      6
      4

(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scalar sub-select:

```
select (select sum(i)
        from unnest(sets) as t(i)) as sum
from matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with postgres in awhile but maybe you're missing the Sum part?:

```
SELECT
  sum(a) AS total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      unnest(sets from matches) AS a
  ) AS b
```